# Initializing objects of other class?

Tags: c#, list, class, object

I have one class with 2 lists as it's data member. I want to include these data members as a different class' objects.

I am getting this error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Kindly advise what should be the proper approach.

```
class dataPoints
{
    public List<double> dataValues;
    public List<DateTime> timeStamps;

    public dataPoints()
    {
      this.timeStamps = new List<DateTime>();
      this.dataValues = new List<double>();
    }
}


//I want an object of dataPoints in this below classs
class wellGraph
{
    int seriesAdded;
    dataPoints[] graphDataPoints;

    public wellGraph(int Entries)
    {
        this.seriesAdded = 0;
        this.graphDataPoints = new dataPoints[Entries];

        for(int i=0;i<Entries;i++)
        {
            graphDataPoints[i].timeStamps = new List<DateTime>();
            graphDataPoints[i].dataValues = new List<double>();
        }

    }
}
```

With the constructor removed in dataPoints class, the same error persists.

Comment: You're never initializing the elements of the array. You need `graphDataPoints[i] = new dataPoints();` before you set the field values. I'd also strongly recommend that: a) you follow .NET naming conventions; b) you use properties rather than public fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instantiate an array of objects, in simpliest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333232/instantiate-an-array-of-objects-in-simpliest-way)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created an array of `dataPoints` (which should be called `DataPoints` according to naming standards of C#), but you have not created the `dataPoints` objects themselves. The elements in the array are all null, hence the null reference exception.

Therefore, inside the for loop, you should create the `dataPoints` objects using `new dataPoints()`:

```
for(int i=0;i<Entries;i++)
{
    graphDataPoints[i] = new dataPoints();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You instancied the array, but not the elements inside.

```
for(int i = 0; i < Entries; i++)
{
    graphDataPoints[i] = new dataPoints();
    // I removed the lines below because they are already initialized in the constructor
    // graphDataPoints[i].timeStamps = new List<DateTime>();
    // graphDataPoints[i].dataValues = new List<double>();
}
```