# Instantiation of every array element(class) - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, instantiation

I have a public class (simplified):

```
  public class opening
    {
        public face side;
        public int start;
        public int length;

        public opening(){}
    }
```

I want an array of `opening` in another class

```
opening[] openings = new opening[4];
```

but when I try to assign a value to it, for instance:

```
this.openings[2].side = side;
```

I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
I can work around it using:

```
this.openings[2] = new opening();
this.openings[2].side = side;
```

but calling `new opening();` for each element of the array feels odd, isn't there an easy way to instantiate every element of the array when creating it?

Comment: _"Isn't there an easy way to instantiate every element of the array when creating it?"_ -> A loop?

Comment: `opening[] openings = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(_ => new opening()).ToArray();`

Comment: You may be better off using a `List` and adding values to that rather than a data structure (array) that implies there are existing elements already there.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333232/instantiate-an-array-of-objects-in-simpliest-way

Comment: @kvp2982, thanks this is it exactly i somehow didn't manage to find it, sorry for the duplicate.  @IanMercer thanks, I'm not used to `List` and therefore didn't consider using it in the first place but it seems better and i will use it!